# Как разместить в ряд три изображения в квадратных областях

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Мне нужно расположить три изображения в квадратных областях в ряд так, что бы при изменении ширины браузера квадраты оставались квадратами.

1. Три квадратных изображения должны всегда занимать всю ширину родительского дива, который тянется вместе с браузером.
2. Изображения должны меняться динамически. Если там будет бакграунд - будет не удобно.
3. Исходные картинки - прямоугольные.

В итоге должно получиться что-то типа этого: [image: ..]

Comment: Перенесите дополнения из комментариев в сам вопрос. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
div {
    background: #737373;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    margin: 1.66%;        
}
div:hover {
    background: black;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTok9GAMciVqTTlxgSojXP8yPNAt1a0iyKexU7YCDEYFr1UgrGo" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTi6yvNhbL_qWDmf0CqCjObIKLOEV8KobtxeYsNPnk0tynHaer0xw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTok9GAMciVqTTlxgSojXP8yPNAt1a0iyKexU7YCDEYFr1UgrGo" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTi6yvNhbL_qWDmf0CqCjObIKLOEV8KobtxeYsNPnk0tynHaer0xw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_WGLGUhf-E74PgPVnISsV2RkX4ahN-jhF7UpOghGmyrI8iTn_bw" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTok9GAMciVqTTlxgSojXP8yPNAt1a0iyKexU7YCDEYFr1UgrGo" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это то, что было нужно! благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку - 3 дива у которых ваши изображения - это бекграунд.
задайте жестко стороны дивов  - и пропорции не сломаются.
также можно прописать `background-size: contain`

опишите подробнее , какое должно быть поведение картинок при расширении / сужении экрана

Comment: При изменении ширины экрана картинка должна оставаться квадратной и масштабироваться.

Comment: Жестко это в пикселях? Тогда надо будет через js менять стиль. Или я могу в css менять высоту при изменении ширины?

Comment: `При изменении ширины экрана картинка должна оставаться квадратной и масштабироваться`

я так понимаю, в таком случае, эти картинки должны меняться и по высоте ? 
или должно увеличиваться между ними расстояние ? ТОгда так http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGBmYJ

Comment: При изменении ширины экрана картинки должны тоже изменяться по высоте и ширине, оставаясь квадратными.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще правильно это делать при помощи img и какого-нибудь wraper'а.
Я просто модифицировал свой пример. Написал небольшой скриптик c использованием jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(
    function()
    {
        var cw = $('.figure').width();
        $('.figure').css({'height':cw+'px'});
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8m71qb16/10/

Comment: Пишу приложение на ionic. JQ туда вставлять не хочется, ведь там есть AngularJs. Хотелось обойтись чистым css.

Comment: Окей. Сейчас будем вспоминать как это сделать при помощи чистого CSS. Вы хотите, чтобы изображения масштабировались по высоте и ширине при изменениях размеров окна?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Не нужны скрипты для этой задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал использовать какой нибудь css framework, например [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), тогда большинство стандартных вопросов с версткой отпадут сами по себе, так как большинство классов уже готовы к использованию и их просто нужно использовать([Про сетки](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)) , если же нужен ответ на Ваш попробуйте его задать более раскрыто, что бы не всплыли подводные камни.